# Rails jQuery custom function for a link click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, function

### What am I doing wrong?.

**Here is the code.**

```
 $("#online-include-out-of-stock a").live("click", function() {

       $(this).out_of_stock("#include-out-of-stock","#exclude-out-of-stock","#online-grid",$(this).attr("href"));

    });

$.fn.out_of_stock = function (clicked_div_id,div_id_to_show,grid_div_id,href_attr) {

  var product_id = href_attr.match(/product_id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
  var sub_category_id = href_attr.match(/sub_category_id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
  var include = href_attr.match(/include=([0-9]+)/)[1];
  var type = href_attr.match(/type=([a-z]+)/)[1];

  if(product_id == "") product_id="0";
  if(sub_category_id == "") sub_category_id="0";
  if(type == "") type="0";
  if(include == "") include="0";

  $.get('/specific/include_exclude/' + product_id + '/' + sub_category_id + '/' + include + '/' + type, function(data){
        $(grid_div_id).html(data);
        $(clicked_div_id).css('display','none');
        $(div_id_to_show).css('display','inline');
    })
    return false;
}
```

I get the following error in firebug,

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/specific/include_exclude/141/1/1/online   

jquery.js?body=1 (line 8103)
ParamsHeadersPostPutResponseCacheHTML
Response Headersview source
Request Headersview source
Host    127.0.0.1:3000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100922 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.10
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
X-CSRF-Token    epUllDUjvfaFXojTrCZjECBiRmmgYHgTRPDrNETY9GI=
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://127.0.0.1:3000/specific/141/1
Cookie  _session_id=4f7c92f56e66871da77690d5e6747258
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I changed to this and it worked.

```
$("#online-include-out-of-stock a").live("click", function() {

   out_of_stock("#online-include-out-of-stock","#online-exclude-out-of-stock","#online-grid",$(this).attr("href"));
   return false;

});



 function out_of_stock(clicked_div_id,div_id_to_show,grid_div_id,href_attr) {

  var product_id = href_attr.match(/product_id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
  var sub_category_id = href_attr.match(/sub_category_id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
  var include = href_attr.match(/include=([0-9]+)/)[1];
  var type = href_attr.match(/type=([a-z]+)/)[1];

  if(product_id == "") product_id="0";
  if(sub_category_id == "") sub_category_id="0";
  if(type == "") type="0";
  if(include == "") include="0";

  $.get('/specific/include_exclude/' + product_id + '/' + sub_category_id + '/' + include + '/' + type, function(data){
        $(grid_div_id).html(data);
        $(clicked_div_id).css('display','none');
        $(div_id_to_show).css('display','inline');
    })

}
```